# Count Number of users logged-in in every 10 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count total unique users logged into the system in every 10 minutes.

I have a table called v_WebTMASessionLog and the columns are sessionstart,  sessionend, user_login_id. The total user need to repeat count who continued using

I'm expecting an output like below

```
Date and time          Number of users
3/25/19 8:00           5
3/25/19 8:10           5
3/25/19 8:20           8
3/25/19 8:30           9
3/25/19 8:40           8
3/25/19 8:50           7
3/25/19 9:00           2
3/25/19 9:10           1
```

Comment: mysql or sql server? which database you are using?

Comment: first see your work ? then ask question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). stack overflow is not code factory.

Comment: @ashish, answer to question is optional for you, not mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SQL Server`, you can do it like following.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Dateadd(minute, ( Datediff(minute, CONVERT(CHAR(8), 
                                                   your_date_column, 
                                                   112),Dateadd(second,10 * 60 / 2,your_date_column)) /10 ) * 10, 
                           CONVERT(CHAR(8), Getdate(), 112)) AS your_date_column 
         FROM   [yourtable]) 
SELECT your_date_column, 
       Count(*) AS Users 
FROM   cte 
GROUP  BY your_date_column 
ORDER  BY your_date_column
```

**Note:** Replace `[yourtable]` with table name and `your_date_column` with date column name.

**Edit:**

> is is possible to start this query with "Select"

Without `CTE` you can do it like following.

```
SELECT sessionstart, 
       Count(*) AS Users 
FROM   (SELECT Dateadd(minute, ( Datediff(minute, CONVERT(CHAR(8), sessionstart, 
                                                  112), 
                                        Dateadd(second, 
                                        10 * 60 / 2, sessionstart)) / 
                                                10 ) * 10, 
                      CONVERT(CHAR(8), Getdate(), 112)) AS 
               sessionstart 
        FROM   v_webtmasessionlog)t 
GROUP  BY sessionstart 
ORDER  BY sessionstart
```

Comment: thanks @PKS, is is possible to start this query with "Select"

Comment: You mean you don't want to use CTE?

Comment: when i tried below query it showing "Invalid column name 'sessionstart'." SELECT sessionstart, 
       Count(*) AS Users 
FROM   (
     SELECT Dateadd(minute, ( Datediff(minute, CONVERT(CHAR(8), 
                                                   sessionstart, 
                                                   112),Dateadd(second,10 * 60 / 2,sessionstart)) /10 ) * 10, 
                           CONVERT(CHAR(8), Getdate(), 112)) AS your_date_column 
         FROM v_WebTMASessionLog
)t 
GROUP  BY your_date_column 
ORDER  BY your_date_column

Comment: Change your_date_column to sessionstart in your inner query.

Comment: @RaneeshRaveendran, I have updated the answer, you can check the second example with your column names

Comment: how to count unique users like Count(DISTINCT user_login_id) AS Users

Comment: you can select userid in the inner query and put count(distinct userid) in outer query.